# How to use a function with paramaters in another function in java

Tags: java, sql

How do I use the function with parameters in another function and use it in condition sql in code java like this:

```
query = "update date set date_fin = '"+dates+"' where id ='"+getid()+"'";
```

Below is my Java code. I have two functions; how do I use the function `getid` in function `updateDatefin`?

```
// get id of line date
public int getid(String date){
    String datedb;
    datedb = date;
    int h = 0;

    try{
       Connection con=ConnectDB();
       Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select id  from date where date_debut = '"+datedb+"' ");
       while(rs.next()) {
           h =rs.getInt("id");
       }
    } catch (SQLException | IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Recognizer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return h;
}

//date time insertion
public void updateDatefin(String date_fin){
    String dates = null;
    dates = date_fin;

    try{  
        Connection conn=ConnectDB();

        String query;
        query = "update date set date_fin = '"+dates+"' where id ='"+getid()+"'";

        // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        // execute the preparedstatement
        preparedStmt.execute();
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data added");

    }catch(SQLException | HeadlessException e){
        System.out.println("errrr");

    }catch(IOException iox){

    }           
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to send the value that you want to use through to the function:

```
query = "update date set date_fin = '" + dates + "' where id ='" + getid(date_fin) + "'";
```

If this isn't the value that you want, simply replace `date_fin` in this line with the parameter that you require.

Comment: in the DB i have a table named date with attribut {id , date_debut , date_fin } and i need to insert the date of start the executing the programe and the end time that ended the progrm executing , so i done insert the date of start and now i need to update the secound attribut { date_fin } with the time ended of executing  , so i make a function to get the id of the line in DB   that i insert the date_db , and i want to update the date_fin  with the end time , so when i create this requet " update date set date_fin = +datefin+ where id =getid() ,

Comment: it dos not work so i need help with how to call that finc and the finc getid it take parameter (date_db) to get the id of that line in the database , i hope u understand me

Comment: Hi @MRInt, what isn't working? This answer shows how to send the parameter through to `getid`, which was the question asked.

Comment: Possibly, you need to pass `date_debut` as a parameter to `updateDatefin` & pass that parameter to `getid`

Comment: Yes thats my problm i need to pass date_db in parameter to updatedatefin so what can i do

Comment: I'd suggest that you edit your question to add all of these extra details. You've added a lot more requirements than your original question was asking. Where do you call `updateDatefin` from? Does it have access to `date_db`? If not, where can you find it?

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function in two ways for this case:

1. Just create a new variable and call function and pass that variable into the query.

String getID=getid(date_fin);

String query;

query = "update date set date_fin = '"+dates+"' where id ='"+getID+"'";

2. Directly call function in query

String query;

query = "update date set date_fin = '"+dates+"' where id ='"+getid(date_fin)+"'";

**NOTE : You have to pass a parameter in the getid function.**

Comment: in the DB i have a table named date with attribut {id , date_debut , date_fin } and i need to insert the date of start the executing the programe and the end time that ended the progrm executing , so i done insert the date of start and now i need to update the secound attribut { date_fin } with the time ended of executing  , so i make a function to get the id of the line in DB   that i insert the date_db , and i want to update the date_fin  with the end time , so when i create this requet " update date set date_fin = +datefin+ where id =getid() ,

Comment: it dos not work so i need help with how to call that finc and the finc getid it take parameter (date_db) to get the id of that line in the database , i hope u understand me

Comment: Share some of the DB entry where you getting stuck not updating them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
  query = "update date set date_fin = ? where id = ?";
  // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
  PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
  preparedStmt.setString(1, dates);
  preparedStmt.setString(2, getid(date_fin));
  // execute the preparedstatement
  preparedStmt.execute();
```

Comment: in the DB i have a table named date with attribut {id , date_debut , date_fin } and i need to insert the date of start the executing the programe and the end time that ended the progrm executing , so i done insert the date of start and now i need to update the secound attribut { date_fin } with the time ended of executing  , so i make a function to get the id of the line in DB   that i insert the date_db , and i want to update the date_fin  with the end time , so when i create this requet " update date set date_fin = +datefin+ where id =getid() ,

Comment: it dos not work so i need help with how to call that finc and the finc getid it take parameter (date_db) to get the id of that line in the database , i hope u understand me

Comment: I got your point now. Isn't it the case that you should pass both date_fin, date_debut to UpdateDateFin()? Because, without date_debut, I don't think you can find the id to update. Am I correct here?

Comment: Yes u ar so what i can do in this case

Comment: then, pass date_debut to UpdateDateFin() and pass the same as parameter to get_id(), which should solve your issue.

Comment: they are not in the same class the call of the func of date_db in  main class , and the date_fin in another class  "rec", and i want to call the func updatedatefin  in the class "rec"  , and i want to pass func getid()  in parameter in call of updatelastdate , what i would do

Comment: is it possible to create an instance of main class in "rec" to get date_db?